# How to pass a uniform to shader

Tags: ios, objective-c, glsl, shader

I'm learning objective-c and I'm quite stack with the following problem:
In my app I want to send a uniform from a class to my shader that will use it in its code. I spent hours in reading posts and I know that I've to use glUseProgram, glGetUniformLocation and glUniform1f, but I don't understand how to implement those.

this is how I init the filter

```
GPUImageFilter *customFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] initWithFragmentShaderFromFile:@"CustomFilter"];
```

And here how I would like to pass the float as an uniform

```
glUseProgram(customFilter);
GLint myUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(customFilter, "myUniform");
glUniform1f(myUniformLocation, 0.345f);
```

the error says to me that I have an incompatible pointer to integer conversion. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You should get the uniform location after you link your program and not everytime you go to use the program. It will not change between program invocations, only after you link it. Because `glGetUniformLocation (...)` searches for uniforms by name (in the form of a string), it is quite expensive to call. More-so than regular `glGet (...)` functions, which you also should not call any more than you absolutely need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a handle to a Shader Program, and not a pointer to GPUImageFilter instance.
A pointer to GPUImageFilter is its address in memory, a handle to a shader program is an index OpenGL uses to identify Shader Programs.

Reading through the GPUImage Source, it doesn't look like GPUImageFilter supports arbitrary uniforms. What you will have to do is subclass GPUImage filter to add that functionality.

Take a look at [GPUImageExposureFilter.h](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageExposureFilter.h) and [GPUImageExposureFilter.m](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageExposureFilter.m) for a good starting place on how to do this.